# well formated table in matlab

Tags: matlab

suppose I have two vectors

$ A=[ 1 ,2, 3, 4]$
$B=[ 5 ,6, 7, 8]$ of the sam length and an additional vector which is "smaller" by one elment, i.e. $C=[9, 10, 11]$. Now I define $\operatorname{display}=[A,B,C]$ and want to print a table, using $\operatorname{disp(display)}$. How do I have to change this "code" s.t. the the elements of C start in the second row? Thanks for you help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to achieve the shift would be to padd C:

```
C = [NaN C];
```

and then use `disp`.